# Can't bind AppSettings to IOptions in .NET 6 console app

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0, ioptionsmonitor

Working in a .NET 6 console app and having problem with binding settings from appsettings.json to IOptions.

Here is my code:

appsettings.json

```
{
    "MyOptionsSettings" : {
       "Foo": 100,
       "Bar": true
    }
}
```

MyOptions.cs

```
public class MyOptions 
{
   public int Foo {get; set;}
   public bool Bar {get; set;}
}
```

program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => 
{
    var configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(opts => configuration.GetSection("MyOptionsSettings"));
    services.AddTransient<MyService>();
});

var app = builder.Build();
var myService = app.Services.GetService<MyService>();
```

MyService.cs

```
public class MyService 
{
    .
    .
    public MyService(IOptions<MyOptions> options)
    {
       _options = options;
    } 
    .
    .
}
```

The `_options` has default values for all the properties and nothing from the appsettings.  I actually want to use the `IOptions<T>` wrapper `IOptionsMonitor<T>` so the settings are dynamic.  However, I can't even get the `IOptions<T>` work.  I think my problem is with the `IServiceCollection.Configure<T>()`.

**Update:**

I just came across a blog that probably solved my issue but I'm not sure why the example above isn't.  Based on the blog, I changed the following line:

From this:

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(opts => configuration.GetSection("MyOptionsSettings"));
```

To This:

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(opts => configuration.GetSection("MyOptionsSettings").Bind(opts));
```

Now the IOptions binds/resolves without any issues. Even Microsoft's console app documentation uses the one above (without the `Bind(opts)`);  What's the difference between those two lines?

Comment: Is that your entire `appsettings.json`? Or just a section under the root?

Comment: I'm showing the entire appsettings.  I will update it with the `{` and `}` so it is a complete json file.

Answer (score 0):

There are [`OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and [`OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) with several overloads former accepting `IConfiguration` and latter - `Action<TOptions>`, so the first one will accept the confiuration from which to  bind the options and second one will require some action to fill the option values. So your original snippet can also be:

```cs
services.Configure<MyOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MyOptionsSettings")); // IConfigurationSection is IConfiguration
```

Or you can use the `Bind` approach, but usually the `Action<TOptions>` variant usually is used for "manual" configuration like:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(opts =>
    opts.SerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never);
```

Comment: @AliBesharati you need to provide more info